# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-file

I am trying to use logstash to push data into kibana, but while running logstash.conf file i am getting error

```
Error Message:  

Sending Logstash logs to E:/dev/logstash-7.9.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-09-09T14:22:48,297][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.9.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.12.0 (2.5.7) 2020-07-01 db01a49ba6 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.261-b12 on 1.8.0_261-b12 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2020-09-09T14:22:49,410][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-09-09T14:22:54,149][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 124 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 22 keys and 45 values
[2020-09-09T14:22:57,211][ERROR][logstash.filters.csv     ] Unknown setting 'seperator' for csv
[2020-09-09T14:22:57,237][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (ConfigurationError) Something is wrong with your configuration.", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.<init>(CompiledPipeline.java:119)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt.initialize(JavaBasePipelineExt.java:82)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.call(JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.gen)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:837)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1169)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuperSplatArgs(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1156)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InstanceSuperInvokeSite.invoke(InstanceSuperInvokeSite.java:39)", "E_3a_.dev.logstash_minus_7_dot_9_dot_0.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$initialize$0(E:/dev/logstash-7.9.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:44)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:82)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:332)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:86)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:939)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", "E_3a_.dev.logstash_minus_7_dot_9_dot_0.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0(E:/dev/logstash-7.9.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52)", "E_3a_.dev.logstash_minus_7_dot_9_dot_0.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0$__VARARGS__(E:/dev/logstash-7.9.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:82)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", "E_3a_.dev.logstash_minus_7_dot_9_dot_0.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.RUBY$block$converge_state$2(E:/dev/logstash-7.9.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:357)", "org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:138)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:52)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:139)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:318)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"]}
warning: thread "Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`
          create at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:129
             add at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:57
  converge_state at E:/dev/logstash-7.9.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:370
[2020-09-09T14:22:57,317][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] An exception happened when converging configuration {:exception=>LogStash::Error, :message=>"Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`"}
[2020-09-09T14:22:57,383][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`>, :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:129:in `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:57:in `add'", "E:/dev/logstash-7.9.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:370:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2020-09-09T14:22:57,498][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

below is code of logstash.conf file:

```
input {
        file {
               path => "D:/Users/manis/Desktop/temp/data.csv"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "NULL"
        }
}
filter {
        csv {
    seperator => ","
              columns => ["Id","Title","Body","Tags","CreationDate","Y"]
        }
        
}
output {
           elasticsearch{
                         host => "http://localhost:9200"
               index => "data"
           }
    stdout {}
}
```

Although my Kibana, and elasticsearch are running perfectly fine, I have tried changing the path of config file,path of data, output format,etc but none worked for me.

Any help in this regard will be helpfull.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the configuration of the elasticsearch output plugin contains an error: it's host**s**, not host. See the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts). Or you're using a really old version of logstash

Comment: my logstash version is 7.9.0 and same is elastic-search and kibana, and tried changing host to hosts, but still same error.

Please help again if you can.

Comment: You'd have to update your answer with the current configuration you're using and the full output of logstash

Comment: Done @baudsp, you can go through it, I am reading a csv file

Comment: There's a typo in your csv filter configuration, it's sep**a**rator, not sep**e**rator.

Answer (score 3):

The error is right there in the log.

```
[2020-09-09T14:22:57,211][ERROR][logstash.filters.csv     ] Unknown setting 'seperator' for csv
```

Use ***separator*** instead of ***seperator***.
Additionally it should be ***hosts*** instead of ***host*** which would be thrown next when ***seperator*** typo is corrected